# Cannot increase partition size although there is free space

Tags: partitioning, gparted, resize

[image: GParted]

I'm running a live session of Ubuntu/GParted through USB. I need to increase the size of `/dev/sdb1` but I do not have that option. I can only decrease. I have 20GB set aside for my increase.

I did search for a while but could not find this exact issue.

Thanks for the quick replies. I'm still not sure how to fix this. I tried making all the other partitions smaller, but can't increase the one I need.

[image]

I reset everything because I don't see how to change what I want. I'll just wipe it and start over this weekend. Aside from being surprised this wasn't easy, I'm surprised I haven't found an explanation for why I can't resize that one partition. Would anyone be able to explain that?

Comment: I thought I attached a screenshot. Let me try again...
http://imgur.com/a/vtwCB

Comment: You have no unallocated space after the partition you want to increase. You'd need to move all the others to the right.

Comment: You need to move the partitions one at a time so the unallocated space is adjacent to sdb1. It will be tricky as the other partitions are logical so you will have to increase sdb2 -> apply changes move -> apply changes mvoe -> apply changes decrease sdb2 -apply changes. One step at at time.

Comment: You don't have to apply changes every time. Gparted can work in batch mode.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replys. I don't think I did this correctly.
http://imgur.com/a/1v4e9

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confused because the empty space is not easily accessible. You need to move all the partitions around to expand the one you want. But just to be sure, I tried a test run on a blank disk.

In short, you need to:

1. Move sdb6 and sdb5 all the way to the right
2. Resize sdb2 (the extended partition) to open up space at its start (left side)
3. Expand sdb1 into the space we just opened up

#### Screenshots:

Setup

[image: GParted screenshot 1]

About to apply changes

[image: GParted screenshot 2]

Done

[image: GParted screenshot 3]

BTW, the disk name "sdb" just happened to match. I didn't plan that.